# ZF2 What is exchangeArray function in Models

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I am using PHP with ZF2 and in its model files there is always a function with name `exchangeArray()`.
The main duty of this function is to fill object properties via an array of data:

```
public function exchangeArray($data)
{
    $this->id     = (isset($data['id'])) ? $data['id'] : null;
    $this->artist = (isset($data['artist'])) ? $data['artist'] : null;
    $this->title  = (isset($data['title'])) ? $data['title'] : null;
}
```

What is this function made for when all the db functions work with array of data and not objects? Sholud we call it or is it automatically called when needed ?!!!

Answer (score 4):

The `exchangeArray()` method is a requirement for form hydrators; specifically the `Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator\ArraySerializable` hydrator so it can access the domain object's protected properties when binding from form fields.

From [the documentation](https://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.stdlib.hydrator.html#zend-stdlib-hydrator)

> **Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator\ArraySerializable** - Follows the definition of `ArrayObject`. Objects must implement either the `exchangeArray()` or `populate(`) methods to support hydration, and the `getArrayCopy()` method to support extraction.